# Is this relation $\mathscr R$ on the set of relations, reflexive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

> Let $S$ be a finite set.
>   Define $\mathscr R(S)$ to be the set of relations on $S$. Define a relation $\mathscr R$ on $\mathscr R(S)$ as follows:
>   $$\mathscr R = \{(\mathscr P, \mathscr Q) \mid \mathscr P, \mathscr Q ∈ \mathscr R(S),\;  a\mathscr P\,b\implies a\mathscr Q \,b \;\;∀\;\,a,\, b ∈ S\}.$$

How do I prove that $\mathscr P$ is a subset of $\mathscr Q$? Thanks!

Comment: That $\mathscr P\subseteq\mathscr Q$ if and only if $\mathscr P$ is related to $\mathscr Q$ via this relation seems to be the definition you just stated. $\qquad$

Comment: On a side note, this would be reflexive right because for all P and Q, they can be equivalent?

Comment: Reflexive means everything is related to itself. $\mathscr R$ is reflexive because for any $\mathscr Q, a\mathscr Qb \implies a\mathscr Qb$, so $(\mathscr Q, \mathscr Q) \in \mathscr R$.